# Error getting object data value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I get an error working with data objects in JavaScript as below:
When I write JavaScript in JSP page:

```
var obj ="${data[0].columns[0].name}";
```

it returns result correctly. But I want index of an array to be dynamic as:

```
var k=0;
var obj ="${data["+ k +"].columns["+ k +"].name}";
```

But it throws an exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+ k +"

Comment: Dear all,
I try to suppose use:

    **var obj = "${data["+ "0" +"].columns["+ "0" +"].name}";**
but i get new error with a exception below:

    **javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${data["+ "0" +"].columns["+ "0" +"].name}]**

My purpose is foreach data list object but i can't put index dynmic array.

Thanks a lot.

An.

Comment: Use ${data["+ Number(k) +"].columns["+ Number(k) +"].name}";

Answer (score 0):

You initialize k with `var k=0;`
Hence it has type int.

The + operator is overloaded, and wants to add k to the memory address of the string --> compile time error.

You should probably use `k.toString()`

Comment: Hi Quandary,
I try to as:
var k = 0;
var obj = "${data["+ k.toString() +"].columns["+ k.toString() +"].name}";
but it's also error. java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+ k.toString() +"
Thanks.
An.

Comment: Is it possible you should use $k ?